# Set SelectedIndex of ListView in FlipView_SelectionChanged event

Tags: c#, listview, windows-store-apps, flipview

I'm building a Photo app using a `FlipView`. In the BottomAppBar, I placed a `ListView` of all the images to be able to view the image in the `FlipView` when I click it in the `ListView` and get the image displayed in the `FlipView`, selected in the `ListView` (like a Pagination).

In the `listView.selectionChanged` event, I made the code that shows the image in the `FlipView` when I select it in the `ListView`. Here is the code:

```
    private void listView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            string CurrentViewState = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Orientation.ToString();
            int IndicatorIndex = listView.SelectedIndex;

            GoToPage(CurrentViewState, IndicatorIndex);
        }

    private void GoToPage(string CurrentViewState, int IndicatorIndex)
        {
            if (CurrentViewState == "Portrait") 
            {
                flipView1.SelectedIndex = IndicatorIndex;
            }
            else if (CurrentViewState == "Landscape")
            {
                if (IndicatorIndex % 2 == 0)
                    flipView1.SelectedIndex = IndicatorIndex / 2;
                else
                {
                    if (IndicatorIndex == 1)
                        flipView1.SelectedIndex = 1;
                    else
                        flipView1.SelectedIndex = (IndicatorIndex + 1) / 2;
                }
            }
        }
```

Now when I need to change the `listView.SelectedIndex` according to the `flipView.SelectedIndex`

```
listView.SelectedIndex = flipView.SelectedIndex
```

I am having an Exception:

```
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in eBookApp.exe but was not handled in user code. Additional information: Value does not fall within the expected range.
```

I need to be able to get the same image selected in the `FlipView`, selected and scrollAt it in the `ListView`...

Comment: Please be more specific than "an exception". _What_ exception are you getting? What is the exact error message from the exception? What is the exception stack trace? Please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem, along with clear, specific instructions for how to use that code example to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I tried editing my question, I added the exception message I am getting and more code, hope this is helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up making it work by adding to my `FlipView`:

```
SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=SelectedIndex, ElementName=listView1, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

and to my `ListView`:

```
SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=SelectedIndex, ElementName=flipView1, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

Their both `SelectedIndex` refer to each other!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Selection Change event, a simpler way is using data binding to SelectedIndex.

```
<Page
    x:Class="BlankApp.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:BlankApp"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <StackPanel Margin="100, 100, 0, 0">
            <FlipView x:Name="flipView1" Width="500" Height="200" SelectionChanged="flipView1_SelectionChanged">
                <Image Source="Assets/Logo.scale-100.png" />
                <Image Source="Assets/SmallLogo.scale-100.png" />
                <Image Source="Assets/SplashScreen.scale-100.png" />
            </FlipView>
            <ListView Name="listview1" SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=SelectedIndex, ElementName=flipView1, Mode=TwoWay}"></ListView>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=SelectedIndex, ElementName=flipView1}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: I tried adding `SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=SelectedIndex, ElementName=flipView1, Mode=TwoWay}"` to my ListView in Xaml but it **didn't work!**

Comment: Have you changed the ElementName to your FlipView Name? in my case, it is flipView1.

Comment: Yes I did, and I removed my ListView OnSelectionChanged event and still when I change the FlipView selection, no items are selected in my ListView